# How to find how many elements to the left of a certain array element are greater than it?

Tags: java, arrays, optimization

Given an array, I want to figure out which element **x** has the most numbers to its left that are greater than **x**. For example, in the array [3, 3, 1, 8, 2, 9], the element 2 has **3** numbers to its left that are greater than itself.

The answer to this question should be the amount of bigger numbers to the left of the value. Here's my obvious brute force solution:

```
    int biggest = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int num = 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < i; j++)
            if (a[j] > a[i])
                num++;
        biggest = Math.max(biggest, num);
    }
```

However, this runs in O(n^2) time which is undesirable. How can I solve this task in a quicker way?

Comment: This sounds like a homework question or something of that nature. The way you benefit and gain value from questions like this is solving them. I think you should take another crack at it and come back with a solution that you've worked a little longer on.

Comment: Could you get me started in the right direction? The original problem wasn't this at all, this is just what I have simplified the problem to. Any hints would help, I'm not sure what to do at this point.

Comment: I don't have the exact algorithm, but what I would say is work your way from right to left. Start at the highest index or val(9) and compare left. If you keep the max index in the array as you scan you can make this a lot quicker

Comment: How would working from right to left help? All I can see adding is checking if the current biggest value is greater than how many numbers there are left to check, and if so then just stopping the loops and returning the current biggest value as the answer.

Also what do u mean by "keeping the max index in the array as you scan"

Comment: Working from right to left helps because it ensures we are starting with the largest number to check that all the numbers to the left are less than it. that helps make it a quicker algorithm.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work, if there was an efficient implementation of `size` for a `tailSet` of a `TreeSet`. But AFAIK it's `O(n)` rather than `O(log(n))` as it could be.

```
int biggest = 0;
TreeSet<Integer> set = new TreeSet<>();
for (int x : a) {
    int num = set.tailSet(x).size();
    biggest = Math.max(biggest, num);
    set.add(x);
}
```

So this is just the idea. It would work if you implemented your own `TreeSet`, where each node would remember the size of its right child. An insertion would be still `O(log(n))`, the size computation would be also `O(log(n))` and the whole loop then `O(n * log(n))`.

This is surely doable, just quite some work.